# Index main-object, sub-objects, and do a search on sub-objects (that return sib-objects)

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I've an object like it (simplified here), Each strain have many chromosomes, that have many locus, that have many features, that have many products, ... Here I just put 1 of each.

The structure in json is:

```
{
  "name": "my strain",
  "public": false,
  "authorized_users": [1, 23, 51],
  "chromosomes": [
    {
      "name": "C1",
      "locus": [
        {
          "name": "locus1",
          "features": [
            {
              "name": "feature1",
              "products": [
                {
                  "name": "product1"
                  //...
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add this object in Elasticsearch, for the moment I've add objects separatly: locus, features and products. It's okay to do a search (I want type a keyword, watch in name of locus, name of features, and name of products), but I need to duplicate data like public and authorized_users, in each subobject.

Can I register the whole object in elasticsearch and just do a search on each locus level, features and products ? And get it individually ? (no return the Strain object)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can search at any level (ie, with a query like "chromosomes.locus.name").

But as you have arrays at each level, you will have to use nested objects (and nested query) to get exactly what you want, which is a bit more complex:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/query-dsl-nested-query.html

For your last question, no, you cannot get subobjects individually, elastic returns the whole json source object.
If you want only data from subobjects, you will have to use nested aggregations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. For the moment I can't do it... Maybe parent/child works better ?